# Show and hide divs

Tags: javascript, html, hide, show

I'm still new to this so yeah... Basically, I've got this drop down element and each option in that element is supposed to direct to a different question (that corresponds to the topic of the option), but once that option is selected, the other unrelated divs are hidden.

So starting at section1 - if sports is selected then it would direct it to #section2 while the other divs are hidden, since they're unrelated.

I don't know how to start it, using javascript - I know it involves the function ShowItem() without using jquery. So, I was wondering if someone could lend me a hand?

The html code:

```
<form id="survey" action="#" method="post">

<div id="section1">
    <label for="color">What is your hobby?</label>
    <select id="hobby" onchange="selection()">
        <option value="sports">sports</option>
        <option value="reading">reading</option>
        <option value="watching">watching movies</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="section2">
    What is your favourite sports?<br>
    <label for="netball">netball</label><input type="radio" id="netball">
    <label for="football">football</label><input type="radio" id="football">
    <label for="baseball">baseball</label><input type="radio" id="vegetarian">
</div>
<div id="section3">
    What is your favourite genre?<br>
    <label for="crime">crime</label><input type="radio" id="crime">
    <label for="fantasy">fantasy</label><input type="radio" id="fantasy">
    <label for="scifi">sci fi</label><input type="radio" id="scifi">
</div></form>
```

I forgot to add the css bit:

```
#section2, #section3 {
    display:none; border:1px solid gray; padding:8px; margin-top:12px; width:400px;
    }
```

Comment: could you show js related code as well, if you'd tried it..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manage it like this

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#hobby").change(function () {
      var str = "";
      $("select option:selected").each(function () {
            if ( $(this).text()=='sports' )
            {
                 $("#section2").show();
                    $("#section1").hide();
                    $("#section3").hide();
            }
           if ( $(this).text()=='reading' )
            {
                 $("#section1").show();
                    $("#section2").hide();
                    $("#section3").hide();
            }

          });

    })
      });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried the code and it still doesn't work. Is the display:none in the CSS affecting it somehow?

Comment: similarly you can set the display:block in style attribute or you can create another style and can set style  like create css unhide { display:block; border:1px solid gray; padding:8px; margin-top:12px; width:400px;} and can change the style using $("div").css("unhide");

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
function selection()
{

  var vHobby = $("#hobby").val();
  if(vHobby == 'sports')
  {
      $("#section2").show();
      $("#section1, #section3").hide();


  }
  if(vHobby == 'reading')
  {
       $("#section1").show();
       $("#section2, #section3").hide();                   
  }
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. can you please tell me what the 'v' means?

Comment: its just a variable declaration standard,  v Means variable.

Comment: oh thanks for clarifying. I haven't gotten it to work yet, though.